# Margin-left pushing div to > 100% and I cannot figure out how to fix it

Tags: html, css

I have a table (designed with divs) of elements that start 170px from the left side of my container. [image: See image]

Thus, I have a margin on the div at 170px. However, by having this margin it's pushing the div to > 100%. This is actually okay when the table doesn't have too many rows (above image), but it pushes everything into a scroll bar (i have overflow-x: auto set) when there are a lot.

[image: stupid extra space]

Here's my css

```
.attendance-sessions {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 170px;

  .session-header {
    height: 150px;
    width: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: $gotham-medium;
    color: $my-gray;

    span {
      width:200px; /* same as height of .session-header */
      display:inline-block;
      -webkit-transform-origin:84px 70px;
      -ms-transform-origin:84px 70px;
      -o-transform-origin:84px 70px;
      transform-origin: 84px 70px;

      -webkit-transform:rotate(-75deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-75deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(-75deg);
      transform: rotate(-75deg);
    }
  }
}
```

erb

```
<div class="attendance-table">
  <div class="attendance-sessions">
    <% sessions.each do |session| %>
      <div class="session-header">
        <span><%= session.date_formatted %></span>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

corresponding html

[image]

Comment: as an experiment set the `transform: rotate();` to `-90deg`. I suspect that the text is slightly overflowing, causing the extra width. @Yitzhak

Comment: @Alex thanks for replying, unfortunately the white space is still all there after switching to -90

Comment: You should really use a table for tabular data - especially if you have table headers for both rows and columns. I would say your code above is as semantically incorrect as using a table for layout.  But if you want us to help, you need to create a [mcve] with your rendered code - the code you provide is neither complete nor verifiable.

Comment: I was going to say the same thing @Pete with regards to using a table. But i'm not sure this is tabular data.

Comment: Yeah I am currently trying to reproduce your problem but with your actual code I can't. As @Pete says the tables exist with the purpouse of handling that kind of approachment you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Alex, looks like some sort of attendance table to me names along the left, dates across the top and a green blob to show they were there on that date?

Comment: @Pete. Hmmm. I can't decide if it is or not. I certainly swayed more to tabular data when i first saw the question, so maybe it is.

Comment: This is indeed an attendance table. When the user clicks the at-the-moment-unformatted dot it is currently sending an ajax request to update the student attendance record for that date. Working on a better example as we speak...

Comment: Please @Yitzhak can you say me if my answer is what you need? English is not my native language. If my answer is what you need I will explain it and if it's not I probably missunderstood his/her purpouse then i will delete it

Comment: I'm simply trying to remove the extra 170px white space on the right side so the page doesn't start to autoscroll.

Comment: Here is a fiddle with broken down code
https://jsfiddle.net/xb0m9y2u/1/ 

Updated by remove variables

Comment: Is the gap caused by the margin or the rotation - your fiddle still does not replicate the problem.  Could you try changing the margin to padding and adding box sizing border box.  If the gap is not there then we know it's probably because you declare a width of 100% somewhere for that attendance-sessions div

Comment: Sorry, never actually uploaded something to jsfille. I got it working and tested it https://jsfiddle.net/xb0m9y2u/3/

The gap is caused by the 170px of margin. I can go into the dom and delete the headers one by one. After ~5 the scrollbar disappears even though the margin is still there. I added box-sizing and it still didnt fix it :(

Comment: @Pete any thoughts on the updated JS fiddle?